# What is the maker and year of this frame with the serial number a2008112

Tags: identify-this-bike

I'm needing help identifying my frame with serial number a2008112 please help[image][image][image]

Comment: You should include at least two pictures to help us identify the frame.

Comment: Ok I'll take a couple

Comment: Any and all help will be greatly appreciated. I've had this frame since about 1996.

Comment: Its a BMX.    You need wheels, BB, cranks, chainring, chain, pedals, rear cog, and to be street-legal you need brakes and possibly reflectors depending on your location in the world.

Comment: I have all that... Pit bull center pull breaks,Flight racing cranks, I've had everything since like 98 just not put together.  I'm trying to find out the maker and year of the frame. I think it maybe a mongoose? Please help me to get positive identification . Thank you for all replies.

Comment: Not much point in storing a bike for nearly 20 years if you're not going to ride it.   Usual comment:   If you got a sweet and loving mongrel bitser dog from the pound, knowing the parents won't change the dog one little bit.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily identify the maker of this bike thanks to the gusset on the frame, it is a Mongoose.

- The serial number starts with A, which tells you it was made in January (A : January, B : February, C : March, etc.).
- Then the second character is a 2, which means it was made in 1982 (last number of the year).

So your bike is a 1982 Mongoose.
According to the manufacturing date, it can either be a Supergoose I or II, or a California Special, but I can't really tell with these picture. You would also need to know the frame material to help figuring this out.

If you need more info, hit that link : http://www.vintagemongoose.com/index.php

Comment: Great work - Do hang around because BMX identification questions are not uncommon here.

Comment: Thanks mtdp's I thought it was a goose I couldn't remember. It's nickel plated. I've had it for many many years . Started to put it together long ago got side tracked by getting a 67 Mustang convertible and restored it. Now my son wants to put the bike together.  So again thank you for your help.  When we finish the bike I'll post some pics of it .